# c++ method parameter change it self only in release mode at linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

in c++ h file:

```
bool getIntValue(QString name,int& dest,int default_value,bool set_default=true);
```

in c++ cpp file:

```
bool CoinConfig::getIntValue(QString name, int& dest, int default_value, bool set_default)
{
    qDebug() << "1 getIntValue set_default=" << set_default;
    if (_Platform_Config->contains(name)) {
        dest = _Platform_Config->value(name).toInt();
        qDebug() << "2 getIntValue dest" << dest;
        return true;
    }
    else if (set_default) {
        qDebug() << "3 set_default=" << set_default;
        qDebug() << "4 getIntValue dest default" << dest;
        dest = default_value;
        qDebug() << "5 getIntValue dest default" << dest;
        return false;
    }
}
```

////////////////////////
run bellow code :

```
int b;
getIntValue("timer", b, -1, false); //_Platform_Config->contains(name) return false
```

got the output:

```
1 getIntValue set_default = false  // at first set_default is false 
3 set_default= true                // change to true  ???   
4 getIntValue dest default 1000
5 getIntValue dest default -1
b 2 -1
```

The set_default parameter change from false to true !!!
the system is linux , in debug mode it is right , but in release mode it is error.

why?

Comment: Is this `getIntValue("timer", b, -1, false);` exactly how the error occurs? Or does the error happen with `getIntValue("timer", b, -1, d);`, where `d` is a `bool` variable? Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g., leave out the Qt stuff?

Comment: i don't know how is occurs, it is right in debug mode,just occur in release mode

Comment: Check that all variables are initialized. Often, uninitialized variables seem to work in Debug and are unpredictable in Release.

Comment: getIntValue("timer", b, -1, false);  the set_default variables is initialized to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing return statement in `getIntValue`. Try adding `return true` or `return false` at the end of the function:

```
bool CoinConfig::getIntValue(QString name, int& dest, int default_value, bool set_default)
{
    qDebug() << "1 getIntValue set_default=" << set_default;
    if (_Platform_Config->contains(name)) {
        dest = _Platform_Config->value(name).toInt();
        qDebug() << "2 getIntValue dest" << dest;
        return true;
    }
    else if (set_default) {
        qDebug() << "3 set_default=" << set_default;
        qDebug() << "4 getIntValue dest default" << dest;
        dest = default_value;
        qDebug() << "5 getIntValue dest default" << dest;
        return false;
    }
    return false; // <--- this is missing in your code
}
```

I recommend that you enable compiler warnings, then the problem is found easily:

```
prog.cc: In function 'bool getIntValue(QString, int&, int, bool)':
prog.cc:27:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: yes, after i add a return statement , it's right now. but , why it change the set_default variable from false to true when where is not such a return statement?

Comment: Because without that return statement your code has undefined behaviour.  See [\[stmt.return\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2).